# php- how to change htaccess to classify home and post page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on a php website . I heard we can change the htaccess to identify whether it is home page, post page or search page.

Currently I'm using the below details.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home.php
```

Where the Index.php gets the url and identifies whether it is home page , search page or url page.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions .

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do here... Your question isn't very clear. In the current format, your code will rewrite `index.html` or `index.php` to `home.php`. Are you wanting to internally rewrite `home.php` to `index.php`, which will do the actual work?

Comment: Nope. I have a script post.php. This is the php file to get details of individual post . For example : http://google.com/how-to-get-details is the page. I want a script to understand the url is the post url and call the corrresponding page automatically. If the url typed is http://google.com it should call main page . if the url typed is search page, then it should call search.php.

Comment: I think that what You are looking for is `routing` please check [this tutorial](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/)